S3 Presigned Url Uploads Throwing CORS error For Other File Types except .txt
I am trying to upload files to S3 bucket using presigned urls. However, only txt uploads work and other types throw CORS error.
Access to fetch at X from origin Y has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
I do have my CORS config setup to allow origin and headers and other regular stuff. But I can't seem to wrap my head around why txt works but other types don't work. I do specify the content type during url generation and also pass it while sending my PUT request.

You need to modify the Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) on the bucket.  This is in the permissions tab of the bucket, all the way at the bottom.
This is an example configuration
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "Authorization"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "POST",
            "HEAD",
            "PUT",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "https://www.example.com",
            "https://subdomain.example.com"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
        ]
    }
]

See this post for more information

I mentioned that i already have the necessary CORS config :)
